# iOS Safari scrolling down website automatically

Tags: html, iphone, scroll, safari, mobile-safari

When using Safari on an iOS device, a website I'm working on  scrolls down automatically:

http://thelimbic.com/

I'm completely unsure why, and have investigated without success:

1. jQuery (I thought perhaps it's using a scrollTop function)
2. CSS (nothing in here suggests an automatically scroll)
3. Image Loading - still unsure about this one, I thought that perhaps the issue is when images are loaded after you're viewing the website it pushes the scroll down?

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever figure out the cause? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: is any of your DOM elements requesting focus on page load? 
i.e. $('.my-element').focus() ?

Answer (score 1):

you can check for any "**autofocus**" attribute given to form fields. Especially in MAC it auto focuses on form field regardless of where your form is placed.

For example:

input type="text" name="fname <strike>autofocus</strike>"

Hope this resolves your problem.